# git svn clone and revision ranges?

Tags: git, svn

When you do a merge in SVN you can specify a revision range like:

```
 [4506, 4605,4784,4869,5081,5146-5148,5150,5418]
```

Now I would like to clones the above revisions into a git repository using git svn clone. I have tried:

```
git svn clone -r 4506,4605,4784,4869,5081,5146:5148,5150,5418 "https://path-to-svn-branch" git_repo
```

But that gives:

```
revision argument: ... not understood by git-svn
```

Does git clone svn only support a single revision or a start:end range?

From:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

It seems that the above should work:

*This allows revision ranges for partial/cauterized history to be supported. $NUMBER, $NUMBER1:$NUMBER2 (numeric ranges), $NUMBER:HEAD, and BASE:$NUMBER are all supported.*

Answer (score 0):

Revision numbers are specified in the format of `-r<number>` or `--revision=<number>`.

If you are going to provide a range, it would be `-r<number>:<number>` or --`revision=<number>:<number>`

Examples:

```
git svn clone -r5146:5148 "https://path-to-svn-branch" git_repo

git svn clone --revision=5146:5148 "https://path-to-svn-branch" git_repo
```